# Target _BLANK doesnot work on some devices

Tags: html

I have a simple link.

```
<a href="http://someurl.com" target="_blank" class="external-link">Link Text</a>
```

And on some mobile devices - it doesnot open the link in the new tab.

Can I somehow fix it? Maybe use a JS code instead? Would be any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is maybe because 'target' works on mouse click, not on finger click in the mobile device. 
try this:

```
Replace 

<a href="http://someurl.com" target="_blank"></a>    

with 

<a href="#" onclick='window.open("http://someurl.com");return false;'></a>
```